# Is there any way to disable the screenshot to the particular website? image can't be save in any format

Tags: javascript, css, web, joomla3.0

I want to create a website, From there no one can steal my photos by screenshot or any kind of download method. if they try to screenshot the particular image also they unable to save any photo format. Is that possible?

Please Let Me Know...

Thanks!!!

Comment: There is no such thing...if it's in the browser anyone can do what they want with it

Comment: and dont you want to prevent user from taking picture of your website by camera?

Comment: Really? Good luck :)

Comment: yup u r right but, its a difficult task that client given it to me!

Comment: @SantoshKokatnur need to explain to client how  web page works... those images get downloaded to users machine each page load. Can open an image url , right click on it and paste it into a photo processing app

Comment: Yeah Sir, @charlietfl !

Answer (score 2):

Preventing screenshots is not possible

Answer (score 0):

```
 {(function() {
var startingTime = new Date().getTime();
// Load the script
var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

// Poll for jQuery to come into existance
var checkReady = function(callback) {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        callback(jQuery);
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(function() { checkReady(callback); }, 20);
    }
};

// Start polling(Add jquery logic here)
checkReady(function($) {
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 44) return false;
    });
});
})()
}
```

Comment: could you explain how this code will disable the functionality of taking screenshot?