# How to Prevent Screenshot for Responsive website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am creating a website, and facing some problem -
I want to Prevent Screenshot in Website when it is tested on Mobile Phone.
I used jQuery for Desktop view It's working fine but how to prevent in mobile

Is it possible to prevent screenshot?

```
 function copyToClipboard() {
  var aux = document.createElement("input");
  aux.setAttribute("value", "print screen disabled!");      
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  // Remove it from the body
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
  alert("Print screen disabled!");
}
```

Comment: I can take another phone and take a picture of my screen. If you do not want people to copy something, don't put it on the web

Comment: Short answer, nope, you can't prevent it.

Comment: Any reason why you want to prevent screenshot?

Comment: Its a requirement from my client @SudharshanNair

Comment: @AnjaliPatel. Actually verify with client why screenshot should be restricted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to prevent screenshots from mobile.

Comment: Are you Sure ? @Chao1920

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android

Comment: I don't want to develop an android app. But When I am checking my website on an android phone through Browser so how can I prevent screen capture?  @Chao1920

Comment: I don't see any solution anywhere. I've been looking all over to my best abilities. 

I keep finding post like these where its says is not possible. Have you not searched through Stackoverflow yourself before asking this question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007905/is-there-any-way-to-disable-the-screenshot-to-the-particular-website-image-can

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I had search but not got the solution so I posted this. @Chao1920